# Hito ki no pan meaning -- 「人気のパン」

Tags: kanji

Ive looked at multiple different searches for hito ki no pan meaning. It looks like "Urikireru" means sold out but I cannot find what hito ki means. Heres a picture. I dont know if this counts as an open ended question or not. Just need help translating the first part. Thanks.

[image: kanji]

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware of the compound 人気{にんき} "popularity"? With that in mind, you should be able to translate the phrase:

> 人気のパンが売り切れる 
> Popular bread sells out.

As a side note, you should probably start using a dictionary. Copy-pasting the unknown word into a resource such as https://jisho.org would easily show you the correct reading and meaning for an unknown word.

Additionally, that's katakana ウ that you've used in the screenshot, which is similar in shape but distinct from hiragana う.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response and I do know the word ninki. It makes sense now. But why did you think that I dont know the difference in the katakana U vs the Hiragana U? I dont think i even mentioned that. Im just trying to understand. Also, I took the picture from a game im playing. How could I write that in Jisho if I dont know the meaning? I guess I could search the web for individual kanji and put them both in if thats what you mean. Ill try that next time. I dont want to have to ask if I can find them easier. I do appreciate it.

Comment: "I guess I could search the web for individual kanji and put them both in if thats what you mean." Yes, that's exactly what he means.

Comment: Sometimes I dont know what the kanji are but I think I should be able to figure out going forward using Jisho like someone mentioned.

Comment: @jogloran the ウ is in katakana because it's a screenshot of a kanji writing question and that's a common way to represent the part that needs to be converted to kanji (along with the red line). The OP is aware they are playing a kanji game, so I think they're familiar with that.

Comment: @FruitBasket it's possible to search jisho for kanji you don't know by using the handwriting tool or the radical picker tool.

Comment: Really? I didnt know that. Thats awesome. I will have to try it. Thank you!